# Windows Service safely save key

Tags: c#, windows-services, filesystems, registry

i have created a Service, and made it run as  `LocalSystem`, because i need it to run independently from the logged-in users, and the service needs to save a key received from a socket, and keep it on the file system or registry. where is the best way to save a file or registry key, keeping the standard users unable to read the key?

found a way to do it, using file system to save config files here:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

the service is running as localsystem, so it returns this:

```
@"C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\"
```

and only the system or administrators can access it.

 if someone has a reason to not use this way, or has a better way, it would be very helpful too

Comment: You don't need to run as `LocalSystem`. All recommendations are that you do not do this. Use `LOCALSERVCE` for example. Don't use `system32` as a place to store things. It belongs to the system, not to you. Finally, everyone can read `system32`, so putting it there won't work at all. You'll need to find a location on the machine and use an ACL to protect it from prying eyes.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan _"**Local Service account** is a built-in account that has the same level of access to resources and objects as members of the Users group"_, this service needs to run as administrator, and i think `localService` can't do it. And it's true that every user has access to `system32`, but not to `systemprofile` folder, only has administrator

Comment: OK, then you ought to find another user. `LocalSystem` is not recommended. You are right about `C:\Windows\system32\config` I agree.